# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException in Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jdbc

I have started getting below jdbc communication error in my spring boot application while trying to find issue i could not find anything wrong with the mysql server and properties file. it seems like there's some issue with connector configuration.

below is dependency code:

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.41</version>
</project>
```

below is the stack trace of an error:

```
12:52:10.879 [restartedMain] ERROR org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool - Unable to create initial connections of pool.
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 253 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 246 milliseconds ago.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.41.jar:5.1.41]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:989) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.41.jar:5.1.41]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ExportControlled.transformSocketToSSLSocket(ExportControlled.java:164) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.41.jar:5.1.41]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.negotiateSSLConnection(MysqlIO.java:4901) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.41.jar:5.1.41]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1659) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.41.jar:5.1.41]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1226) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.41.jar:5.1.41]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2205) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.41.jar:5.1.41]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2236) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.41.jar:5.1.41]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2035) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.41.jar:5.1.41]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:790) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.41.jar:5.1.41]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.41.jar:5.1.41]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.41.jar:5.1.41]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:400) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.41.jar:5.1.41]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:330) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.41.jar:5.1.41]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:310) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.11.jar:?]

Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1946) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:316) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:310) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1639) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:223) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1037) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:965) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1064) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1367) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1395) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1379) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ExportControlled.transformSocketToSSLSocket(ExportControlled.java:149) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.41.jar:5.1.41]

Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:397) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:302) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:262) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:330) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:237) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:132) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1621) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:223) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1037) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:965) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1064) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1367) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1395) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1379) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ExportControlled.transformSocketToSSLSocket(ExportControlled.java:149) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.41.jar:5.1.41]

Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:392) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:302) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:262) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:330) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:237) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:132) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1621) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:223) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1037) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:965) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1064) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1367) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1395) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
```

Comment: Using with SSL? If yes then you can use https://github.com/escline/InstallCert this program to install a certificate for the server in JDK

Comment: use java `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=truststores/client.ts com.progress.Client`

also try with this
`-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\jre\lib\security\cacerts`
-Djava.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit`  in your eclispe.ini file